# PySide2 (5.11.x): Unable to call type(QtWidgets.QWidget).__new__ in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside2

We have a metaclass based on `type(QtWidgets.QWidget)` -- which resolves to `Shiboken.ObjectType` -- that we've had in production dating back to PySide/Qt4 that's breaking in the versions of PySide2 that are on pypy (5.11.x). Earlier alpha versions of PySide2 (2.0.0~alpha0) do not have this problem.

If you call the following from Python 2.7 using a 5.11.x version of PySide2, you'll see that it appears as though `Shiboken.ObjectType` is passing through arguments it's given to `type.__new__`, which isn't allowed.

This line of code is contrived just to illustrate the problem, hence the empty name, parents, and class_dict arguments, and passing the type in as-is. In our production code, that would be the metaclass we're defining, and the remaining arguments would be passed through from input args/kwargs:

```
type(QtWidgets.QWidget).__new__(type(QtWidgets.QWidget), "", (), {})
```

In PySide2 5.11.x, the following is raised:

```
TypeError: Shiboken.ObjectType.__new__(Shiboken.ObjectType) is not safe, use type.__new__()
```

In PySide/Qt4 or PySide2 2.0.0~alpha0, the correct return occurs:

```
<class '__main__.'>
```

Has anyone run up against this before? Are we doing something fundamentally wrong, or is there a workaround we could employ? Something in shiboken2 has changed, but I'm unsure if it's a bug or if our code is simply incorrect and there's something we can tweak to make it work.

Comment: I've opened a bug ticket with the Qt Foundation here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-816